# How to remove large space between 2 words for justify alignment in mobile device?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Wtu.jpg)I used **text-align: justify;** but sometimes it showing large **space** between two words. That's why I am trying solve it for mobile device and used **text-justify: inter-word;** for removing space but it's not working.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
```

.mobile-con{text-align: justify !important; text-justify: inter-word;}

}

**Html**

```
<p style="text-align: justify;" class="mobile-con">
                           Star aims to be the world class consortium of choice by
                            delivering projects within time & budget and to the 
                            required standards of quality by the fusion & best
                            application of human intellect & ethics with the 
                            combination of modern technology. 

                        </p>
```

How can I solved it?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the actual and desired behavoir?

Comment: Is it possible to use JavaScript? You can use regex to replace all 2 spaces with a single space, called recursively to end up with a single space

Comment: web site url: http://starconsortiumbd.com/about.php

Comment: I attached a picture.

Comment: @NitinSingh Please give the script.

Comment: Maybe you could solve this with `word-break: break-all;` For more Infos, look here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: @rojadesign Thank you very much. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-all;` to break all words to fit in the defined width.